# Typeahead not calling search API when typing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, typeahead.js, typeahead

trying to implement the typeahead search in nodejs with mysql, but can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

When manually going to http://localhost:5000/search?key=s for example, I can see the result and my debug logs in the console. but when typing in the input text, it's not showing anything nor can't see the console.log("debug") in the console so looks like the /search is not even called

EDIT: now I can get to the API callback and have my debug logs, I can see the result when doing console.log(data) but nothing is displayed on the screen, there is no dropdown with the list of suggestion within data and I also have this error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4' in ["Sep

Any ideas ? something wrong with the asyncResults(data) ?

here is my code:

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="typeahead tt-query" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" name="typeahead" type="text" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                highlight: true,
            },
            {
            name: 'Name',
            display: 'value',
            source: function(query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
                $.get('/search?key=' + query, function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    asyncResults(data)
                });
            }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js** :

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const port = 5000;

// create connection to database
// the mysql.createConnection function takes in a configuration object which contains host,user, password and the database name.
const db = mysql.createConnection ({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'raid',
password: 'raid',
database: 'raid',
port: 3308
});

// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
console.log('Connected to database');
});
global.db = db;



// configure middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', process.env.port || port); // set express to use this port
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // set express to look in this folder to render our view
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // configure template engine
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse form data client
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // configure express to use public folder
app.use(fileUpload()); // configure fileupload

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
// routes for the app

app.get('/raid', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
})

app.get('/search', function(req, res){
    console.log("debug")
    db.query('SELECT Name from champions where Name like "%'+req.query.key+'%"',
    function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var data=[];
    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        data.push(rows[i].Name);
    }
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});


// set the app to listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: edit: slightly changed how I call typeahead, now I can see the result when doing console.log(data) but no dropdown is displayed + having error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4' in ["Sep

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue with the following :

```
var Name = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/search?key=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
        });

        $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'Name',
        displayKey: 'Name',
        source: Name,
        display: function(data) { return data.Name; }
    });
```